# Switch colors when circles spread to more than 75% of the screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have made an animation, where circle `div`s enlarge and fill up the entire screen.
[You can see the animation here](https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation).

When the screen is about 75% covered by the circles, I want to start the animation all over again with circles of different colors, i.e., I would essentially be treating the old circles as the background screen and start new circles with a different color over the old ones.

The code I have till now is this:

```js
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

function makeDiv(divColor,bgColor){
    var divsize = 1000;
    $('body').css({'background-color':bgColor});
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': divColor,
        'transform': 'scale(0)'
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'border-radius':'50%',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var colorArray = ['green','red','blue','orange','violet','yellow','pink'];
    var arrayLength = colorArray.length;
    var i=0;
    var id = setInterval(function(){makeDiv(colorArray[i],'white')},3000);
});
```

```css
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: expand 2500s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(100.0,100.0);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There are two major issues I am facing:
1. How to detect that 75% of the screen is covered by circles of the particular color?
2. Switch colors once the above has been detected.

My plan till now is to run a sort of loop, which when detects that the screen is 75% covered, switches colors.

Any help is most appreciated. I am really stuck at this problem since a long time.

Comment: Personally I would use time, rather than screen coverage percentage to handle this - time is the best constant between CSS animations and your JavaScipt. Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: I have no problem with that too! As long as the animation works!

Comment: So I would first tackle one limiting factor - you're using JavaScript to add CSS directly to your page. Ideally, you would want your JavaScript to add elements or add classes to elements, with CSS picking up the rest of the work of positioning and styling your elements. Then, it will be trivial to add a new class after a delay that changes the colour.

Comment: Also, on line 2 of `makeDiv` you set a fixed size and then apply it to the div - if this is fixed, this should also be applied in CSS. You are calculating the X/Y position of the divs, so that can remain in the JavaScript.